# Php create an accessed object when its null (like __isset())

Tags: php, class, properties, isset

I understand that __isset() is for a non exists property. But I want it on an exists property which is null.
By default it could be good:

```
class myClass
{
 public function __isset($name)
 {
  // create an object;
 }
}

$a = new myClass();
$a->mails->get();
$a->users->login();
```

but mails, users object are nowhere in declaration. So this could be the solution, but it results in a distorted class, it reflects bad in on UML diagram, etc. Real solution could be:

```
class myClass
{
 public $users = null;
 public $mails = null;
 public function __isset($name)
 {
  // create an object BUT IT WONT TRIGGER!
 }
}

$a = new myClass();
$a->mails->get();  // <- fail!
$a->users->login();
```

just because users, mails are declared. But it then now reflects the good structure! Singleton could be good already, but I dont want it. Is there a way to trigger something when something which accessed is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit]

If it's possible to make the properties `private` then access them via `function` maybe you can do something:

```
public function get_Property($property_name) {
    if (!isset($this->{$property_name})) {
        echo "\n Property : '$property_name' cannot be accessed because it is not set or is null \n";
        // or create your object here then return it;
    else {
        return $this->{$property_name};
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but CheckCredentials() wont trigger when accessing a property which is null

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend not to broke the encapsulation and use getters and setters instead of direct fields addressing. Also, it will solve your problem by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, maybe stating the obvious and leaving aside the various reasons why your implementation at the moment cannot work, why dont you just do:

```
public function getMails()
{
    if (!$this->mails) {
        $this->mails = new ... whatever ...;
    }

    return $this->mails;
}
```

If you need some service to get the mails, inject it in the constructor:

```
private $mailService;

public function __construct($mailService)
{
    $this->mailService = $mailService;
}

public function getMails()
{
    if (!$this->mails) {
        $this->mails = $this->mailService->magicallyFetchMails();
    }

    return $this->mails;
}
```

Not sure why you want to expose your object properties.